# How to set CloudFront Distribution Description?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

[Terraform's docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution) doesn't say anything about any `Description` field. Neither Googling (which's is problematic in the first place, as `Description` is super-common word).

I tried adding a `Description` `Tag`, but it doesn't show up in the `Description` column of the [CloudFront > Distributions](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/v3/home#/distributions) page

Comment: did you tried to add `comment`, I think it will solve your purpose https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution#comment

Comment: Let me know if it helped, would be happy to post a answer :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra - yes, please. Seems you came before [Ben Whaley below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080984/587467)

Comment: Added an answer, thank you for asking this interesting question, hope it help others in the future :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a description using [comment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution#comment)

AWS console uses description ( console is misleading :D) however the cloudfront API uses `comment` to denote description. Terraform mapped API name `comment` into its HCL

> comment (Optional) - Any comments you want to include about the distribution.

Comment: Perfect! except tiny detail: it's not Terraform, apparently, who made this mismatch: seems like [it's coming from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDistribution.html#cloudfront-CreateDistribution-request-Comment)

Comment: Thank you so much for the API documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you’re looking for [the comment attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution#comment).